# Dynamically use Foundation Interchange on the same image

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am searching for a way to use Zurb Foundation's Interchange to work on a single image. In my code I **change the image 'data-interchange'** attribute of another set of images and run the following command:

```
 $(document).foundation('interchange', 'reflow');
```

However the image stays the same as the first image, it's not being updated to reflect the change in the data-interchaneg attribute and show the new image.

Is there an option to make it work?

Comment: Same problem for me, i use angularjs to change the data-interchange attribute, and when i fire ```$(document).foundation('interchange', 'reflow');``` nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works when 'reflow' and then 'resize' events are called.

```
    $('img#your-image-id').attr('data-interchange', new-params);

    $(document).foundation('interchange', 'reflow');
    $(document).foundation('interchange', 'resize');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found the answer to your problem.
But I also faced same issue and interchange was not working for me either.

But after some digging, I moved all JS files to footer and all of the sudden it started working and swapping images as it should. These are my scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.interchange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

when updating data-interchange do not use the jquery
`.data('interchange','NEW VALUE')` function, you have to use
`.attr('data-interchange','NEW VALUE')`.

then call the reflow function.